# References from C# Class project not being included in .dll output

Tags: c#, web-services, class, dll, reference

I need to expose a third party vendor's web service internally on my network.  The reason for this is the third party web service requires some custom header information which means it cannot be called from SSRS.  Here is what I have done:

- Took the WSDL files from the vendor (only available offline) and created .dll files (we will call them vendorWS.dll)
- Created C# Class project (myWS.dll) which references vendorWS.dll with copy local set to true.  This project has methods for each method of the vendor service which takes the same input type as the vendor service, calls the vendor service, and returns the same output as the vendor service.

Now I created a test project that references myWS.dll and am trying to call the methods I created.  However, my test project does not recognize the input/output types to my methods and suggests that I may be missing a reference.  It seems that the information on the input/output types from vendorWS.dll is not being included in myWS.dll.  Is there any way to get this information to all be bundled in myWS.dll?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Visual Studio does not automatically load the references needed by a DLL that a project references. So you have to reference the DLLs that your library references.

Ex:

LibA references LibB

AppA references LibA

Visual Studio will not load LibB for AppA unless you tell it AppA also needs it by adding the reference.